Why do this heap pointers print different addresses?
If I'm correct, both printf should show that the variables have the same address, because in the meantime nothing has been allocated to the heap, but it shows different addresses.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *heapTop = NULL;

int main()
{
    printf("sbrk(0):%p\n", sbrk(0));
    heapTop = sbrk(0);
    printf("heapTop: %p\n", heapTop);

    return 0;
}

output:
sbrk(0):0x5b1033f6e000
heapTop: 0x5b1033f8f000


"in the meantime nothing has been allocated to the heap"  Are you sure?  What does your program do in between the two calls to sbrk(0) ?

Hint: not nothing.

It does a printf, but does the printf allocate memory on the heap?

Do you have any particular reason to think it shouldn't?  printf is a very complicated function. And note well that even supposing that it frees all memory it allocates does not imply that a call to printf couldn't affect the program break.  Your experiment appears to show otherwise.

Hmm ok. But then if I want to make a program that directly changes the heap (in my case I'm making an implementation of malloc) there's no way to debug it using printf, right? The only other option would be to use gdb then?

@Jojo: printf might allocate memory only the first time it is called, or just the first time it is called with a non-trivial format string. So you could call it once, then do your thing with sbrk. Keep in mind this will be specific to your C implementation and not portable.

If the allocation is standard I/O buffer-related, you could call setbuf(stdout, NULL); before the first use of stdout (e.g. by printf), or you could use dprintf on the fileno(stdout) file descriptor (which should be file descriptor 1). This is assuming the printf type calls do not do any allocations other than to initialize the stream buffer, such as for handling formatting.

… But the printf-type calls might very well call malloc internally for handling formatted output in certain circumstances. Glibc's printf-type functions may use malloc when printing some high precision floating point values, but will preferably allocate memory on the stack with alloca if the amount to be allocated is not too large.

You need to test it without calling printf or any other functions which may allocate memory on the heap.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void *heapTop = NULL;
void *heapTop1 = NULL;
void *sbrk(intptr_t increment); 

int main()
{

    heapTop = sbrk(0);
    heapTop1 = sbrk(0);
    printf("heapTop: %p\n", heapTop);
    printf("heapTop1: %p\n", heapTop1);
    printf("sfter printfs: %p\n", sbrk(0));

    return 0;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/1PsojdP9j
The result is the same and after printf it changes :
heapTop: 0x46f000
heapTop1: 0x46f000
sfter printfs: 0x490000

For example write does not allocate memory on the heap in the implementation used by godbolt
https://godbolt.org/z/8EnPTf5bY

Oh, ok, thx. So is there any other way i can look to the heap to debug a program since i can't use printf?

@João implement your own one - or get simple printf implementation from internet. Remember that some other functions may use heap as well - test it

Oh, thats good. Thanks!

@João you can still use printf, if you provide your own buffer for stdout stream. Read about function setvbuf.

@Moses assuming that it is the only dynamic allocation,

@0___________ well, yes. Looking at his code - I don't see anything else, that uses heap. And generally, clean C without any libraries and frameworks doesn't use heap that often. stdio, strdup... what else?

@Moses how can you know what his implementation is doing? The assumption that printf is allocating memory for buffers is wrong as we do not know.

@0___________ his output of sbrk is showing exactly that - stdio utility allocating dynamic memory.

@Moses providing your buffers might not be enough if you did not understand what I wrote.
